# Case Sensitive Selection of Next Occurrence in Xcode

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, macos, editor

In Xcode, we can select the next occurrence of a selected sequence of characters by pressing Option + Command + E, but this finds the next occurrence of the selected text case-insensitively. How can we do this case-sensitively?

Comment: Press "Command-F" for Find, and activate the "Aa" button in the toolbar at the top of the editor window.

Comment: Option + Command + E is "***select*** next occurrence", not just "find next occurrence". Do you want selection as well?

Comment: @Sweeper: Good comment.  I edited the question.

Comment: Command + F + (clicking on Aa) affects the searches performed through the search box but it is not having any effect on selecting the next occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode version 13.4.1 has recently fixed this problem and Martin R's comment has become the solution. Now you can select a sequence of characters in your code and then press Option + Command + E to select the following occurrence of the sequence. You can repeatedly press the same key combination to select as many occurrences as desired, which is useful for quickly renaming variables or replacing a text pattern in the code with another text pattern. The search is performed case-sensitively if "Aa" is on, which can be set in the search box brought by pressing Command + F. If "Aa" is off, then the search is done case-insensitively; for example, if "RandomNumber" is selected, then pressing Option + Command + E would select "randomNumber" or "RandomNumber" as the next occurrence. When I asked this question, a case-insensitive search was performed always regardless "Aa" was on or off.